# How to clean reinstall Win 7 without Install disc

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, windows-installer, hp-pavilion

I want to reinstall one really old Windows 7 Home Prem. It was installed in laptop yet by seller. I searched and found just option `Choosing an advanced recovery method->Return your computer to the factory setting` but there is not option to reinstall Windows.

Is there any way to find original install package on disk, put it on USB and than clean install Win 7 on this laptop?

And also where can I find Product key of my windows. That on the bottom of my laptop is unreadable :(

Comment: You shouldn't need anything more than [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) in order to retrieve your license key.  It is far easier to use an [installation disk](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) to accomplish your goal instead of trying to accomplish your task without it.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it is much more far easier to use installation disk but I don't have it :( Laptop seller sold it with Win installed without installation disc. Anyway thanks for recommendation speccy, I'll try.

Comment: So download it?  Its unlikely the require factory partition still exists.  Restoring the computer to the factory setting would accomplish your goal.

Comment: @Ramhound I want clean install, format whole disk and make partitions. So I don't want to restore to Factory settings.

Comment: What you want can only be accomplished by using an installation disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery

You can verify your key and download an iso image there.

This howtogeek page gives you more information and direct download links to digitalriver.net hosted Windows iso's:

http://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/

Note: you do need a valid license code to validate the installation once installed, of course.

/edit: just read your addition that you don't have a valid license code. Be sure to retrieve your code before you start reinstalling anything.

Good luck!

Comment: I have License code but it is damaged. I'll try to get it using some third party software. I'll check links you posted. Thanks a lot for this moment for fast response.

Comment: Yeah, there's a bunch of applications for that. If your Windows installation is still running, I'd give Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder a try too. Have heard a lot of good stories about that (though don't have experience with that myself).

Comment: I had used Speccy as Ramhound recommended and than also Belarc Advisor.. Both gave me same Key, then I inserted it on MS site you gave me in link but there was some problem with it.. I wrote to support and they said that it was just one-time usable key (OEM)